My app uses multiple 3rd party libraries. How can I handle their licensing obligations?
Let's say my application is main.py.
And it imports 3 libraries and uses their functions.
Library A is BSD licensed. Library B is MIT lisenced. Library C is Apache 2.0 lisenced.
Which license files do i need to include to main directory in this case?
Do I need to add 1 of my own licenses that do not conflict with these(btw appreciate it if you could suggest a license that does not conflict with these), and 3 of their licenses?
I did not change the source code of the libraries.
https://www.tldrlegal.com/license/apache-license-2-0-apache-2-0
Include a "NOTICE" file with attribution notes included. Including the full text of license in modified software.
https://www.tldrlegal.com/license/bsd-3-clause-license-revised
Describes whether the original copyright must be retained. Including the full text of license in modified software.
Including the full text of license in modified software. Include a "NOTICE" file with attribution notes included. etc.
I read it but I didn't quite understand it.

All three of the licenses you mention (BSD, MIT and Apache 2.0) are permissive licenses. This means that you are completely free in choosing a license for your own code.
To fulfill your obligations under the licenses of the libraries, you must make sure that the recipients of your application receive a copy of the text of the three licenses and also a copy of the NOTICE file that may be included in the Apache-licensed library.
It is up to you if this information gets distributed as additional files together with the application, or if the application has a screen to display license and attribution information.
As a matter of goodwill and clarity, it is advisable to not just give the bare licensing and attribution information, but to also indicate which part each license applies to. For example, like this:

The main program is under license X. It uses Library A under the BSD license, Library B under the MIT license and library C under the Apache 2.0 license. The license texts are reproduced below.


Hi thanks for answer. Did I get right? I will write all the libraries I use and their licenses in a text file. Then I will copy the license explanations and notices under them. Would a total of two different txt files be enough? One for real license, the other one is for 3rd party libraries I had a hard time finding an example on Github. That's why I asked here.

@disp0, the important thing is that the information is available. How many files is not relevant, so two text files should work.

@disp0 For Apache I recommend you read the section about the "NOTICE" text file. That's one license which gives specific requirements about putting this specific notice in its own place (either in a separate file, or in a specific screen in the application, if applicable).

@BartvanIngenSchenau Thanks for answer. My last question: Can I paste the contents of the NOTICE file below the license file? Assume software named software name 1
For example:
3rdpartylisences.txt:
software name 0
MIT text
...
software name 1
apache 2.0 text
NOTICE
text of the NOTICE file
...
software name 2
BSD text
...

@Brandin I read it but I didn't quite understand it. Do you know if the example I gave in the above comment is ok?

@disp0, The Apache license provides exactly 2 way to handle a NOTICE file: 1. Put the contents in a file called NOTICE; 2. Provide a screen in your application showing the contents. If you have multiple dependencies under the Apache license, you can combine the contents of their NOTICE files into one NOTICE file, but you cannot put it in a "3rdpartylicenses.txt" file.

@disp0 The Apache license says it must be a "within a NOTICE text file". In my opinion that means the file should be named "NOTICE", or "NOTICE.txt", or "NOTICE.text" or something like that. For an example please see the file NOTICE in Apache Subversion: https://github.com/apache/subversion Note that if the program is Apache licensed but does not have a NOTICE file, then you don't need to add one (but you may if you wish). That's because the Apache license precedes that section with the words "If the Work includes a 'NOTICE' text file ..."

Thank you for the replies.
